# How do I remove rows in a Pandas dataframe that have the same values in different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Items | notebook | ballpoint | pencil | eraser | pencil sharpener | stapler | paper | scissors | glue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| image1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| image2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| image3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| image4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| image5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I want to delete rows that have multiple `1`  in different columns, so it become like this:

| Items | notebook | ballpoint | pencil | eraser | pencil sharpener | stapler | paper | scissors | glue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| image3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| image4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| image5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with the [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) of matches or values (if only 0/1) as reference:

```
out = df[df.drop(columns='Items').sum(axis=1).lt(2)]
```

Or:

```
out = df[df.eq(1).sum(axis=1).lt(2)]
```

Output:

```
    Items  notebook  ballpoint  pencil  eraser  pencil.1  sharpener  stapler  paper  scissors  glue
2  image3         0          0       0       0         1          0        0      0         0   NaN
3  image4         0          0       0       0         0          1        0      0         0   NaN
4  image5         0          0       0       0         0          0        0      1         0   NaN
```

Intermediate indexing Series:

```
df.drop(columns='Items').sum(axis=1).lt(2)
# or
# df.eq(1).sum(axis=1).lt(2)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a numpy mask:

```py
df[np.sum(df.values[:,1:]) < 2]
```

should be faster than a pandas based computation.